# How do I write an Rspec controller test that makes sure an e-mail is sent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, actionmailer, rspec-rails

Currently in my controller spec I have:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CustomerTicketsController do
  login_user

  describe "POST /create (#create)" do
    # include EmailSpec::Helpers
    # include EmailSpec::Matchers
    it "should deliver the sales alert email" do
      # expect
      customer_ticket_attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:customer_ticket)
      customer_mailer = mock(CustomerMailer)
      customer_mailer.should_receive(:deliver).
        with(CustomerTicket.new(customer_ticket_attributes))
      # when
      post :create, :customer_ticket => customer_ticket_attributes
    end
  end
end
```

In my controller I have:

```
  # POST /customer_tickets
  # POST /customer_tickets.xml
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer_ticket.save
        CustomerMailer.sales_alert(@customer_ticket).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @customer_ticket, notice: 'Customer ticket was successfully created.' }
        format.xml { render xml: @customer_ticket, status: :created, location: @customer_ticket }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.xml { render xml: @customer_ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My test currently produces the following output:

> ```
> Failures:
>
>   1) CustomerTicketsController POST /create (#create) should deliver the sales alert email
>      Failure/Error: customer_mailer.should_receive(:deliver).
>        (Mock CustomerMailer).deliver(#<CustomerTicket id: nil, first_name: "firstname1", last_name: "lastname1", company: nil, referral: nil, email: "firstname1@example.com", phone: "555-5555", fax: nil, country: nil, address1: "555 Rodeo Dr.", address2: nil, city: "Beverly Hills", state: "CA", postcode: "90210", question: "The answer to the universe is 4.", type: nil, status: nil, priority: nil, number: nil, cs_rep_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>)
>            expected: 1 time
>            received: 0 times
>      # ./spec/controllers/customer_ticket_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>
> Finished in 0.52133 seconds
> 1 example, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/controllers/customer_ticket_controller_spec.rb:9 # CustomerTicketsController POST /create (#create) should deliver the sales alert email
> ```

Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could check the ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count to ensure it has incremented by 1.

Something like this (untested)

```
expect {custom_mailer.deliver}.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
```

Comment: I put the `post :create, :customer_ticket => customer_ticket_attributes` inside of the expect block, and that seems to be doing the job.

Answer (score 1):

The mocks you're setting up don't match what is actually being executed. You'd have to actually be calling `deliver` on that mock you're creating.

Something like

```
message = mock('Message')
CustomerMailer.should_receive(:sales_alert).and_return(message)
message.should_receive(:deliver)
```

should pass.

If you want to check what is passed to `sales_alert` what you're doing won't work - active record only ever compares objects by primary key equality so the customer ticket you're creating in the spec won't be equal to the one created in your controller.

One thing you could do is

```
CustomerMailer.should_receive(:sales_alert) do |arg|
  ...
end.and_return(message)
```

rspec will yield whatever `sales_alert` is called with and you can do whatever checks you want

Another way of doing it to is to stub out `CustomerTicket.new`, so that you then control what it returns, for example

```
mock_ticket = mock(CustomerTicket)
CustomerTicket.should_receive(:new).with(customer_ticket_attributes).and_return(mock_ticket)
mock_ticket.should_receive(:save).and_return(true)
CustomerMailer.should_receive(:sales_alert).with(mock_ticket).and_return(message)
```

Finally you might decide that this alert sending should really belong in an instance method of `CustomerTicket` in which case your controller spec could just check that a `send_sales_alert` method was called on the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

This is way how to test that Mailer is called with right arguments.

```rb
delivery = double
expect(delivery).to receive(:deliver_now).with(no_args)

expect(CustomerMailer).to receive(:sales_alert)
  .with(customer_ticket)
  .and_return(delivery)
```